# Is writing beyond the size of smaller size member in a union UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, unions

According to my knowledge on `union` is that it is like a `struct` and the main difference is that `union` all members share the same memory. While every struct's member has its own distinct memory.

Also enabling a member is through writing to it which is exclusive to the the others. And trying to read from disabled member is considered a UB.

The size of a union is as much big as the biggest member data type. OK. But What I thought:

If I have an array let's say of characters which is a member of my union and whose size is smaller than the biggest member in the union. So when enabling this member (array of chars) Can I write to beyond its size? but not beyond the size of the largest member. In my case (double).?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum TYPE { PAGE, TITLE, WEIGH };

union UBook {
    TYPE tp;
    int    nPages;
    char   szTitle[4]; // only 4 bytes
    double weight;
};


int main() {

    cout << sizeof(UBook) << endl; // 8 bytes (size of double)

    UBook book;
    book.szTitle[0] = 'W'; // for sure correct
    book.szTitle[1] = 'e'; // for sure correct
    book.szTitle[2] = 'l'; // for sure correct
    book.szTitle[3] = 'c'; // for sure correct
    book.szTitle[4] = 'o'; // is this correct?
    book.szTitle[5] = 'm'; // is this correct?
    book.szTitle[6] = 'e'; // is this correct?
    book.szTitle[7] = '\0'; // eigth byte

    //book.szTitle[8] = '\0'; // crash
    //book.szTitle[9] = '!';  // crash

    cout << book.szTitle << endl;

    cin.get();
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program above works fine on many compilers But I am keen to know whether it is correct or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161508/discussion-on-question-by-wonfeihong-is-writing-beyond-the-size-of-smaller-size).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> book.szTitle[4] = 'o'; // is this correct?
> ```

No, it is not correct. It is Undefined Behavior

> ```
> book.szTitle[5] = 'm'; // is this correct?
> ```

No, it is not correct. It is Undefined Behavior

> ```
> book.szTitle[6] = 'e'; // is this correct?
> ```

No, it is not correct. It is Undefined Behavior

> ```
> book.szTitle[7] = '\0'; // eigth byte
> ```

Still Undefined Behavior

**tl;dr** accessing an array outside of its bounds is undefined behavior. Period. No *except* or *unless* clause.

Comment: 'undefined behavior' means something like 'result not guaranteed'. How about `union example { char firstmember[8]; char secondmember[4]; }`. Is example.secondmember[5] not guaranteed to be identical to example.firstmember[5]?

Comment: @anneb "'undefined behavior' means something like 'result not guaranteed'" no. UB means the standard doesn't mandate any behavior of the program. i.e the program can have absolutely any behavior. And when I say any behavior I do mean **any**

Comment: *accessing an array outside of its bounds is undefined behavior.* however this is very common technique use this - when we worked with variable (not known at compile time) size structures. when we declare in the of structure 0 or 1 size array. but later by fact access more bytes. and despite some things (about unions) is formal documented as UB, by fact union is only shared memory (or register). and all members share it. and layout is also known (despite formal it also UB, but without this impossible binary communications, if use union as parameter). so in practic we can use this knowledge

Comment: @rbmm Yes, people rely on undefined behaviour all the time, and presume because it worked last time they are not doing anything broken.  There are ways to do this that result in efficient machine code, but does not involve fake sized arrays and undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Yakk - *but does not involve fake sized arrays* - this not i invented. this is very wide used in windows programming. for example - [`FILE_NAME_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545817(v=vs.85).aspx) and exist huge count of such types structures

Comment: @RbMm Windows API is C (where this structure is legal) not C++ where this is not, unless you have a compiler extension.  The question is tagged language-lawyer so standards compliant answers/comments preferred and exceptions/extensions to the language should be highlighted.

Comment: @RichardCritten - Windows API is C++ not less than c. i for example use always c++ and despite this use windows api as well. and com. no any different between c and c++ in this point. UB is exit out from actually allocated array size, but not from formally declared. in concrete case declared 4 but allocated 8. because this not UB here. this what I try to say. and allocated exactly 8 (size of double), because all union members start at the same address

Comment: @RbMm You appear not to understand what is going on here.  You appear to be saying "it works, so it must not be undefined behavior", which is wrong.  I would advise you to ask a question about this on a site that might give you an answer, say via an ["Ask Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button on a site like stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Yakk - I not say here *"it works, so it must not be undefined behavior"*. i explain own position - write out from **declared** (but not **allocated**) array size not UB. yet one concrete example `struct X { int a; char c[1]; }` - where align of `X` is 4 (align of `int`) so size of `X` is 8 (must be multiple align). as result write to `c[1,2,3]` still will be not UB. unlike to c[4] already error - out of allocated size. and about *All inion members start at the same address* - i explain why this must be with concrete examples. but nothing objected on this, only in documentation another and all

Comment: @RbMm you are in a grave error. Writing/reading to/from `c[1,2,3]` in your example **is** undefined behavior.

Comment: @bolov - may be formal and not defined. but structure in my example have 8 bytes of memory. from which 1 byte explicitly allocated for `c` and 3 implicitly. what undefined in practice can be in this case ? concrete example ?

Comment: about *All union members start at the same address* - I also add absolute concrete arguments and explanations [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161508/discussion-on-question-by-wonfeihong-is-writing-beyond-the-size-of-smaller-size) - why this true and will be true always, despite standard. no any counterarguments. only link to standard and all

Comment: @RbMm concrete example: your program can crash. Because crashing is a behavior that falls under undefined behavior. Concrete example: the compiler can analyse that code and observe that that write is UB. As such it can safely assume under the standard that a valid program will not execute that instruction and as such it can optimize the program by removing the entire branch containing that instruction. And if the function that contains that will always execute that instruction then the compiler can assume a valid program will not call that function and so it can eliminate the function entirely

Comment: @RbMm if you want to know more the wonderfull world of UB, you can read this series of posts from llvm: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: from my observation - compilers not do this currently. and doubt that will be do in future

Comment: @RbMm read the articles. You will be surprised what compilers did in real world when they got smart enough to detect UB in more and more cases.

Comment: @bolov - I already not first time have dispute here about concrete unions. and already not once view this link and read. however you not give me concrete contr arguments about  union member layouts. simply and absolute concrete question - are possible use union in cross binary communication ?

Comment: @RbMm I am talking to a wall here. This discussion is over as far as I am concerned.

Comment: I do not argue about what is written in the documentation. but I cite specific logical arguments, why I think that something is right. -you from your side no any logical argument - simply UB because this is written in standard. even not reply me to simply question - are correct , based on standard have function interface such `void fn(VARIANT* p)` - **yes** or **no** ? (`VARIANT` containing union with different members by size). are this allowed by standard ?